# How to use jwt token to access API in server side component in nextjs 14?

Tags: next.js, jwt, server-side-rendering, next.js13, server-side

I have a login compoent (Client Component) when the user logged in. the backend which is made separately in nest js (not next) provide the jwt_token. Now I am showing all the users on users page which server side rendered. How can I store this token properly to put in Authorization header to have access of all API's. I did the same in react where I have stored the token in local storage but here in server side local storage did not work. Also I don't want to make the whole component client just for this token

Here is my users component

```
async function getData() {
 const token='abc'
 const res = await fetch('apiurl',{cache:'no-store',
headers:{
  'Authorization':  `Bearer ${token}`
}})
 
 
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
 
  return res.json()
}

const UsersPage = async () => {

   const users = await getData()
  return (
    <div>
        <ol>
           {
            users?.map((user,ind) => <li key={ind}>
              <Link href={`/users/${user.id}`}>
              {user.businessName}
              </Link></li>)
              
           }
        </ol>
    </div>
  )
}

export default UsersPage
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach in this case is using cookies. You can set the cookies on the NestJS backend or just set them when the responses from the backend arrive with status 200, and validate this on middleware, like:

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import {verifyIfIsValidToken} from './verifyIfIsValidToken'

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  
  function  isAuthenticated(request:NextRequest) {
      
  const token =  request.cookies.get('x-server-token')
  
  if(token) {
      return  isValidToken(token)    // boolean
  }
    return false
  }
 
  // Call our authentication function to check the request
  if (!isAuthenticated(request)) {
    // Respond with JSON indicating an error message
  
  return Response.json(
      { success: false, message: 'authentication failed' },
      { status: 401 }
    )
  }
  
  return request
}
```